# What character encoding I should use to save a JPEG file using a text editor so it remains a valid JPEG file? (asking for an XML Parsing issue)

Tags: xml, image, encoding

This question is not a duplicate of [Opened a Jpeg file with notepad, pasted all the text to another notepad and saved, now my jpeg file does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/782692/opened-a-jpg-picture-with-notepad-pasted-all-the-text-to-a-new-notepad-file) because all the answers to that question list the problem but offer no solution.

Also, I am trying not to sound like a person who does not know about encoding, I went through [a painfully long refreshing blog post about encoding](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) before writing this question.

My question is basically about trying to find a suitable character encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, Japanese JIS Shift, Roman Macro etc). What character encoding I should view a JPEG file as in an editor so that if I save it using that same encoding, my jpeg still works when I open in an image editor?

Ok before you answer/comment with "it's a binary file, open it in hex editor don't use encodings", I should let you know that the purpose of my question is not that I am trying to open and save JPEG files in text editors.

**Here is what I am trying to do**

I am designing a web service that will exchange request in XML in which one element will contain a blob data in binary. Now since XML is a Text document so it could go through a parser, we are trying to embed that binary blob within a text document.

Now I know there are ways to do that such as encoding the blob into `base64` sequence or a `yEnc` sequence. But that is not my question. My question is, is there a text-character-encoding that can allow me to just embed the raw binary data within the XML? I am able to build an XML like the following using a Hex editor.

[image: XML with binary data embedded shown in hex editor]

Notice the `..` and `?` where the text viewer could not figure out what those code-points were because viewer was using `ANSI`.

Now, assuming there is no single character encoding that is suitable to represent all the special characters in a jpeg file and I have to work with binary. Can I treat the above XML as a big binary blob of xml document and load it into the parser? Do parsers support XML coming in as binary text?

EDIT: I found the answer to the above by writing a simple app, the `.NET 4.6.2`'s XML Parser rejects such XML.

Comment: Is there a text character encoding for binary data? No, there isn't, because they are contradictory terms. It's like asking for an image format that can encode video... No, [wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF)... :)

Comment: Using a text-editor for binary data is a bad choice.
But if you really insist: The best encoding would be `ISO-8859-1`
because it essentially does no translation
between bytes (`0x00 .. 0xff`) and characters (`'\u0000' ..'\u00ff'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML can get as complex as you want but it has reasonably simple basic rules. Among them, the [list of valid characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML). Your own screen-shot illustrates that a typical JPEG file has a fair amount of `00` bytes:

> code point U+0000, assigned to the null control character, is the only character encoded in Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646 that is always invalid in any XML 1.0 and 1.1 document.

In short, the encoding choice is irrelevant if a given char you want to represent is invalid anyway. You would be able to generate something that loosely resembles XML but is not XML.

The only solution is of course the one you already discarded: encoding as plain text (base64, uuencode, you name it).

In any case, using XML to store binary data does not work well in practice. It bumps data size and requires a carefully written pull-parser to not exhaust system memory.